# eval to interpret new lines in bash

Tags: bash, echo, eval

I have a previously run command `$cmd`, this command outputs multiple lines.

I would like to take the `nth` line of output from running an edited version of `$cmd`.

So far I have tried:

```
local -a lines

for line in $(eval "$(some_edit $cmd)");do
  lines+=("$line")
done

echo "${lines[$nth_line]}"
```

I always `echo` everything when `$nth_line` is `1` and nothing for larger integers.

I always have `$lines` being an array of one string - which is all the lines.

I have tried combinations of `"`, but to no avail.

Comment: while you're certain to hear "don't use eval", aside from that, we can't tell what you input and expected output is supposed to be. Please edit your Q to include some samples of input that is failing and the exact output you get from that. Good luck.

Comment: [Don't use `for` to read lines](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: `... | awk NR==$nth_line` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if i understand you correct - you mean something like that?

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd="./script.sh"

# read stdout from $cmd into array lines
readarray lines < <($cmd)

# edit the second line
lines[1]=$'version: 0.99\n'

# loop over array and print lines
for line in "${lines[@]}"; do
   printf "%s" "$line"
done
```

**testscript for simulate $cmd**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "start"
echo
echo "do something"
echo
echo "end"
```

**output**

```
start
version: 0.99
do something

end
```